# Running Kafka on Windows but getting Access denied exception for logs folder

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've been trying to run both zookeeper and kafka 2.13 on my local windows machine. I have modified the server properties to point to c:/kafka/kafka-logs and zookeeper data to point to c:/kafka/zookeeper-data.

The zookeeper starts without any issues but when I attempt to start kafka with

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

I get the below error saying AccessDeniedException. I have already tried the below:

1. Deleting the kafka-logs and zookeeper-data folders and running both zookeeper and kafka again - I still run into the error if I do that
2. Creating the kafka-logs folder before running kafka - I still get the access denied exception
3. Running the command prompt as administrator before typing the commands - does not work

[image]

Could anyone give some suggestions on how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is the kafka version you are using?.

I has this issue in `3.0.0` . I downgraded to `2.8.1` and the issue is resolved.

I think it is something related to kafka.

Comment: Thank you! This works, not sure what the reason is.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the same issue with Kafka 3.0. Downgrading to 2.8.1 will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).